# setOnPreferenceClickListener Help, Forclosing when activity launches

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I know this cannot be as hard I think it is. I am sure I have everything that I can suppose to to implement my onClickListener. Am I missing something, why does this forceclose? I have provided the stack to take a look at. Any help would be great. This was suppose to be a simple activity to save user settings. If I comment out this code the activity displays the activity.

```
Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("customPref");

customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() { //this line forcecloses every time i run the activity.
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                       "The custom preference has been clicked",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             .show();
        SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
        editor.putString("myCustomPref", "The preference has been clicked");
        editor.commit();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Logs:

```
07-10 16:36:47.137: WARN/System.err(1042): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 16:36:47.147: WARN/System.err(1042):     at com.nyneaxis.android.mpg.Preferences.onCreate(Preferences.java:22)
07-10 16:36:47.147: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-10 16:36:47.157: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-10 16:36:47.157: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-10 16:36:47.157: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-10 16:36:47.157: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-10 16:36:47.167: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 16:36:47.167: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-10 16:36:47.167: WARN/System.err(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-10 16:36:47.167: WARN/System.err(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 16:36:47.177: WARN/System.err(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-10 16:36:47.177: WARN/System.err(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-10 16:36:47.177: WARN/System.err(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-10 16:36:47.177: WARN/System.err(1042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like `findPreference("customPref")` is returning `null`. Can you check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `customPref` variable is null. Make sure you have preference with key `customPref` in your preference xml (if you use one) or maybe you've misspelled the key there.

Comment: See I knew it was simple as that.